# Read the position and content of every UI components of foreground view, even outside that App?

Tags: android, android-view

I need to get the position(on real screen) and content of UI components while keeping that view in the foreground. Any way (use service, adb or root privilege) is OK.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look at `HierarchyViewer`

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

It will give you layout information of all components in the layout hierarchy (including non-visible views, etc)

Be sure to visit the link on that page here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

if you're trying to use 3rd party APKs, you can probably do that using the SmaliDebugging, but I haven't tried...

https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/SmaliDebugging

You have to decode the APK, etc.

Comment: Read that. I need finish everything in command line so I think I'll use `uiautomator`. I see there is `Compile your test cases into a JAR file and install it on your test device along with your app`, does it mean I need to recompile that App with my test cases or it's ok to go with any 3rd-party App without making any changes to apk files?

Comment: I edited my response for 3rd party apps - haven't tested it, as I haven't had a need to do this with 3rd party apps. Hope it helps.